# idb file and IDA

Tags: ida, windows, pe, exe

I've just received from a friend a `*.idb` file  concerning the `pe` file i'd like to disassemble in `IDA`. What the file is and how can i load/use it with the `exe` linked with it in IDA?

Answer (score 3):

> I've just received from a friend a *.idb file concerning the pe file i'd like to disassemble in IDA.

a IDB file is IDAs primary project/database format

its the result of an IDA exe load + analyze run

> What the file is and how can i load/use it with the exe linked with it in IDA?

just open it with IDA